# how to target differnt apps from same webpack config file based on command line arguments to npm start command

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, html, webpack-dev-server

I have 3 different reactjs applications having similar dependencies. Can I use same webpack.config.js file to run these different apps. Following is the directory structure I want

```
-root
  --App1
     ---source
     ---index.html
     ---style.css
  --App2
  --App3
  --package.json
  --node_modules
  --webpack.config.js
```

in `package.json` I have following start script

```
"scripts":{
   "start":"node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --progress --port 3000"
}
```

I have tried by using command line argument while issuing `npm start` command:

```
npm start App1
```

And then using `process.argv` in `webpack.config.js` to set the entry point and output path.

```
var path= require('path');

var app= path.resolve(__diname,process.argv[process.argv.length-1]);

module.exports = {

 entry: path.resolve(app, 'source/app.js'),

  output: {
    path: app,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
 .......
 .......
```

webpack loads and compile the files in `App#/source` folders but dosen't serve the content from the `App#` directory. What is my mistake here and  is there any other alternative to get this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another config file, say webpack.config.app1.js for building App1, just like this:

`webpack && webpack --config webpack.config.app1.js`

and so on.

Another way is to make your webpack config from object to array, containing those three object of config.